# Windows: how to get just the user ID of a specific logged in user (active or not) from command line

Tags: windows, user-accounts, id

In Windows, thanks to `query` command line tool I can get, among other things, the local users with their IDs, logged on my computer. How can I get just the ID of a specific user (active or not) using command line?

Comment: `wmic useraccount get name` will give you a list of account names. For each name, `wmic useraccount where name='theUsernameToLookup' get sid` will get you their SID.